# Looking for a good way of texturing a keyboard keycaps

Tags: modeling, texturing

Is there any good and efficient way of texturing a mechanical keyboard keycaps? I made a mesh, but now I need to texture it, and I faced two problems I am not sure how to solve.

1. I have more than 60 keycaps, and every keycap has its symbol or text. Is there any way of texturing it fast and precise? Maybe not fast, but precise.
2. I'm modeling those keycaps for RGB mechanical keyboard (Keychron K2 v2) and I need to make material for my letters and symbols to be translucent.

Can I do it by tweaking texture nodes, or do I need to mess with my mesh (add vertices for the letters&emboss it)?

[image: Something like this]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to find a black and white keyboard map that suits you, use it as a reference to model your keyboard:

[image]

In your image remove everything except the letters themselves, choose the top orthographic view and unwrap your mesh with the *Project from View* option, move the UVs until they fit (here a simplified version):

[image]

Now you can use the image as a mask (as a factor in a *Mix Shader* for example) to create a separation between the basic plastic material and the letters material:

[image]

You can use a blurred version of your image and a *Bump* node in order to create a bit of fake relief around the letters:

[image]

Comment: This solved my problem, perfect. Thank you!